# ListView not getting refreshed automatically, no matter whatever i try

Tags: java, android, listview, signalr, android-arrayadapter

**I know that this has been asked many time and even I have solved this kinda problem many time but somehow I am so struck at this point that I can't make it work anyway I try doing it. Can you guys please look in to this**

I am creating a **Chat App** in Android and .NET using `SignalR framework`, and I have been successful in achieving this at model level in Android but things are going weird with the view.

**-** `SignalR Server` is  `C# based console App` here.

**-** `SignalR Client` is `Android` based.

**Components:**

**Message_Activity:**

`has_Method_To_Send_Message_To_SignalR_Server()`

`static_Method_To_Render_The_Message_Received_From_Custom_Api_Class()`

**Custom_Api_Class (Non Activity):**

`method_invoked_From_SignalR_Server_To_Pass_Message_&_Then_Pass_To_Message_Rendering_Method_In_Message_Activity()`

**The Flow:**

**-** Message is sent **from** `Message_Activity` **to** the `Console C# SignalR server` over the network.

**-** `Server send` this message to the **destined client**, by invoking the `remote call` to the method present in the `Custom_Api_Class`.

**-** Then this method pass that **message** to `static Message Rendering Method` in Message_Activity`for display in the`ListView`.

**Problem:**

**-** After the message is being received from the `Custom_Api_Class` into the `Message_Activity` class for the display of it over the `ListView`, its not showing up... **until and unless the** `ListView` **is being scrolled up or down**.

**Conclusion:**

**-** I understand its a problem of `ListView` not getting refreshed and I did try the below methods to solve it but all in vain...

**-** Called `notifyDataSetChanged` on the `ArrayAdapter`

**-** Called `invalidateViews` on the `ListView`.

**-** Tried by adding the value into the `ArrayList<String>` which goes into the `ArrayAdapter`

**-** Tried by adding the value into the `ArrayAdapter` directly.

**-** `android:stackFromBottom="true"`
      `android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"`

**Can anyone please let me know whats the core problem here is and any solution out of it.. I will be more obliged if someone can help me out of this.**

**Edits:**

**Code in Custom_Api_Class(Non-Activity) called by SignalR Server:**

```
 Subscription subs = hub.subscribe("receiveMessage");
     subs.addReceivedHandler(new Action<JsonElement[]>() {

      @Override
      public void run(JsonElement[] obj) throws Exception {     

MessageActivity.receiveText(obj[0].toString().replaceAll("\"","")+" "+obj[1].toString().replaceAll("\"",""));


        }
});
```

**Code in Message_Activity called by Custom_Api_Class:**

```
public static void receiveText(String msgFromUser) {

        mAdapter.add(msgFromUser);
        listView_Message.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Select the last row so it will scroll into view...
                listView_Message.setSelection(mAdapter.getCount() - 1);
            }
        });
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


    }
```

Comment: post the code where you add item to the listview

Answer (score 1):

Try to scroll programmatically your listView. Something like this:

```
 index = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
 View v = listView.getChildAt(0);
 top = v.getTop();
 adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
 listView.setSelectionFromTop(index + numOfNewElements, top);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well after hell lots of trial and error here is my answer to my own question.........

**-** I figured it out, my `UI thread` was being **busy** and the **hint** that i got from was `Toast`, when i was doing my `System.out.println()` it **worked** well but `Toast` **didn't worked**.

**-** So i created a `Non-UI Thread` and then posted the output to the list from within the `Handler` inside it.

**-** Voila !! It worked like butter.

**Code:**

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            handler.post(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    mAdapter.add(msgFromUser);
                    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    listView_Message.invalidateViews();
                }
            });

        }
    }).start();
```

Answer (score -1):

Try following code

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    //automatically disappear after given time and start game
    public void run() {
        //call your loadingTask here

    }
}, refreshInterval);
```

Hope this will help you

Answer (score -1):

I'm giving the same answer again. It's spectacular how many people is not using Content Providers.

In your situation you have a network operation, holding data in memory is not very effective way to approach your problem. You should persist data to local SQLite database after you receive it. An your list view should observe that data, and show it. Luckily there is `ContentProvider`s and `CursorAdapter`s for that. In documentation it says you don't need a `ContentProvider` and it's correct to some extent but you can add a notification URI to your cursor.

What you should do is load your `Cursor` from SQLite database using a `CursorLoader`, and use your `ListView` with a `CursorAdapter`. On your SQLite helper you should set a notification URI for data and register a `ContentObserver` to force load that data. Your adapter will get new cursor after every change on underlying data. You'll be happy like a puppy.

Comment: Why to involve SQLite database for such trivial problem, its like a temporary chatroom where any two people can talk to each other...... Moreover holding the data in Collection and then updating it over the listView is quite technically correct.... pls provide me the reason why its not working in this particular scenario....

Comment: It's technically incorrect. Application can be shutdown by OS anytime. You'll lose your data. For more information see [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHXn3Kg2IQE)

Comment: **First** of all its **NOT technically wrong**, **Second** OS can **only intervene** in closing of the app when the app is **partially visible or completely invisible** but still running...... But i am talking about **the stage when the app is fully visible and OS can't close the app at this stage**. And lastly... I am not bothered about from where the data is coming but i am worried about the listView not adapting to the change... For now please stop telling about the ContentProvider, just let me know why the ListView is not adapting the changes.

Comment: Can you prove your argument, I'm interested.

Comment: You don't have to get aggressive. You just said "...when the app is fully visible and OS can't close the app at this stage" I really would like to see some proof of that.

Comment: Sorry if my gesture seemed bit aggressive... and i apologize for the same... But try keeping an app on the foreground (which apparently not running a heavy process intensive task on the UI thread) and don't let the lights of your phone to get off, you will see it running as long as you don't close it.

Comment: Yeah, but in case of an incoming call OS will kill current application running on UI.